# database firestore users and groups (ManyToMany)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I wanna look up **groups belonging to a user**. 
and I wanna look up **users belonging to a group**.
(like ManyToMany)

How can I make models?

I tried: 
[] is a collection 
{} is a document

```
users : [
  "uid1" {
   "name" : "jack",
   "age" : 22,
   "groups" : [1, 2]
   },
   "uid2" {
   "name" : "jack",
   "age" : 22,
   "groups" : [1, 2]
   },
  "uid2" {
   "name" : "hori",
   "age" : 21,
   "groups" : [3, 4]
   },
  "uid3" {
   "name" : "dora",
   "age" : 31,
   "groups" : [3]
   }
]



groups : [
  "1" {
   "title" : "science",
   "memberCount" : 22,
   "members" : ["uid1", "uid2", "uid3"]
    },
  "2" {
   "title" : "history",
   "memberCount" : 34,
   "members" : ["uid5", "uid7"]
    },
  "3" {
   "title" : "math",
   "memberCount" : 34,
   "members" : ["uid4", "uid8", "uid11"]
    },
  "4" {
   "title" : "english",
   "memberCount" : 52,
   "members" : ["uid2", "uid3", "uid7"]
    }
   ]
```

Is it correct? If yes, how can I make a query?

Answer (score 1):

you should change the collection "members" in [] to a Type "array":

```
groups : [ // remain collection
  "1" {
   "title" : "science",
   "memberCount" : 22,
   "members" : ["uid1", "uid2", "uid3"] // not in collection but a real array Type
    }
]
```

then you can query groups belonging to a user:

```
CollectionReference groupsRef = db.collection("groups");
groupsRef.whereArrayContains("members", "uid2");
```

more detail: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains

Comment: but firestore rules said that avoid to use array, I think we should use subcollection instead of arrays